# Google App Engine blobstore createUploadUrl 404 not found on server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, multipartform-data, blobstore

I am using blobstore API to upload an image to my app. This works fine locally, which means image is successfully uploaded and callback works as well. But when I am sending the multipart request to the uploadurl returned by createUploadUrl from the server, it always gives me 404 not found error.
Is it possible that blobstore is not enabled for my app? Why can't I see my blobstore in the google cloud console? I have to go to here https://appengine.google.com/blobstore/ to see my blobs.

Code on the app side: doPost handles callback and doGet returns the uploadUrl (both within same servlet /_ah/admin/new_image). doPost(call back handler code) is never triggered and neither is image is uploaded.

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws IOException {

    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("image");
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
    String imageUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKeys.get(0)));
    Long businessId = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("business_id"));
    String linkUrl = req.getParameter("link_url");
    Long id = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("advertisement_id"));
    AdvertisementManager.addNewAdvertisement(id, imageUrl, linkUrl, businessId);
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws IOException {

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    resp.setContentType( "text/html" ); 
    String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("");
    Logger.getLogger("").log(Level.WARNING,uploadUrl);
    out.print(uploadUrl);
}
```

Code to upload an image: First send a get request to get the upload url, then sends the multipart request with the image File

```
public static void upload(Long id, File file, String linkUrl, Long businessId){
    HttpClient httpclientget = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://app-url/_ah/admin/new_image"); 

    String uploadUrl = "";

    try {
        HttpResponse responseGet = httpclientget.execute(httpget);
        uploadUrl = EntityUtils.toString(responseGet.getEntity());
        Logger.getLogger("").log(Level.WARNING,uploadUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    String uri=null;

    try {
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(uploadUrl);
        builder.setParameter("advertisement_id", id.toString());
        builder.setParameter("link_url", linkUrl);
        builder.setParameter("business_id", businessId.toString());
        uri=builder.build().toString();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
    System.out.println(uri);
    if (file!=null){
        MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        reqEntity.addBinaryBody("image", file, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), "ad.jpg");

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity.build());
    }
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(response);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the /_ah/* space is reserved for internal GAE services and you shouldn't use it. The reason you are getting a 404 is probably Google preventing you from deploying that servlet, try changing the URL.